# Combine multiple queries in 1 in grafana

Tags: azure, prometheus, grafana

I would like to combine my queries in Grafana. I have multiple queries that I would like to combine into 1 table.

The contents of A, B, C are just simple azure metrics for different resources. Ex.

```
A = count by (resourceGroup) (azure_metric_postgresql_heartbeat{}) or vector (0)
B = count by (resourceGroup) (azure_metric_sqldatabase_heartbeat{}) or vector (0)
C = count by (resourceGroup) (azure_metric_mysql_heartbeat{}) or vector (0)
```

Expected result:

| resourceGroup | Count |
| --- | --- |
| rg 1 | 4 |
| rg 2 | 5 |
| rg 3 | 1 |
| rg 4 | 9 |

I want to basically compute the number of all resources which is grouped by the resource group.

The challenge here is that some resources are not present in some resource groups.

In the previous example, I added a component table to show the example breakdown of the resources.

| resourceGroup | Count | Component |
| --- | --- | --- |
| rg 1 | 4 | 2 sql, 1 postgre, 1 mysql |
| rg 2 | 5 | 3 sql, 0 postgre, 2 mysql |
| rg 3 | 1 | 0 sql, 1 postgre, 0 mysql |
| rg 4 | 9 | 9 sql, 0 postgre, 0 mysql |

I tried to use the merge and add transformation but am resulted with NaN on fields that don't have resource:
[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with thanos, but I don't understand what are you trying to do with Grafana. Why do you need a new "query", if just three queries for each independent part show do the same. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I have updated the question. I realized that there was an issue with my previous query. I clarified the intent of my query now.

Answer (score 0):

To perform count like you described you can use regex selector over `__name__` label (it contains name of the metric).

In your case you'll need something like this:

```
count by (resourceGroup) ({__name__=~"azure_metric_.+_heartbeat"})
```

or this:

```
count by (resourceGroup) ({__name__=~"azure_metric_(postgresql|sqldatabase|mysql)_heartbeat"})
```